# InflateException on Orientation Change

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-orientation

Whenever I change my screen's orientation, my application crashes with the following exception. I believe it has something to do with the ImageViews causing the emulator to run out of memory, but I'm having trouble understanding the stack trace.

In ProfileActivity.java (where I would like to allow the orientation to change), I try to save and restore the instances of my ImageViews like this, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_beer_profile);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        ratingImages = (List<ImageView>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("ratingImages");
    } 
}

@Override protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("ratingImages", (Serializable) ratingImages);
}

@Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

}
```

However, I get the following runtime exception:

```
04-01 17:34:29.836 25455-25455/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.myapp, PID: 25455
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myapp/com.myapp.myapp.ProfileActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #269: Binary XML file line #269: Error inflating class <unknown>
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #269: Binary XML file line #269: Error inflating class <unknown>
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
  at com.myapp.myapp.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:46)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #269: Error inflating class <unknown>
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
  at com.myapp.myapp.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:46) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
  at com.myapp.myapp.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:46) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4284912 byte allocation with 2835528 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:136)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
  at com.myapp.myapp.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:46) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**EDIT:** I tried this on a physical device, and it does not crash. However, I'd still like to know how best to avoid this issue in the emulator. I would imagine that running out of memory on an emulator could mean that I am not handling the ImageViews correctly on orientation change.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe it has something to do with the ImageViews causing the emulator to run out of memory

More accurately, it is the images that you are putting into the `ImageView` widgets that is the immediate cause of the crash.

> but I'm having trouble understanding the stack trace.

Whatever layout you are inflating in `com.myapp.myapp.ProfileActivity`, in its `onCreate()` method (line 46) has an `ImageView` that points to a drawable resource that, when loaded, would require 4284912 bytes when decoded. That is equivalent to a 1035px x 1035px image.

This is rather large.

Moreover, you do not a free block of memory big enough for it. Partly, this is because you are already consuming a lot of memory, as you only have 2MB of heap space available overall, let alone in a single block.

> I try to save and restore the instances of my ImageViews like this

That is not possible.

Tactically, take a look at the layout, find the `ImageView` widgets, find which one(s) have very large images, and stop using those very large images. You might also wish to confirm what resource directories you are using, and consider using lower-resolution versions of the image for lower-density screens.

Strategically, you need to take ownership of your memory consumption. You can generate a heap dump and use tools in Android Studio (or elsewhere) to see what is in your heap and what is taking up so much space. Unfortunately, Google has not bothered to document the heap analysis tool in Android Studio, but [this bit of documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html) covers other aspects of memory management, and [this page](http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/memory-monitor/index.html) covers the memory monitor, showing you a real-time graph of your heap usage (and from where you can trigger the heap dump, via a toolbar button).